# Why is Debian's chromium-driver package renamed to chromium-chromedriver on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

Why does Ubuntu rename this package? Debian's name is less "enterprise-ready".

https://packages.debian.org/buster/chromium-driver

https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/chromium-chromedriver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just renamed - they're different packages completely in functionality and how they work.

In Debian, `chromium-driver` doesn't have a dependency on Snaps.  Debian packages the Chromium driver directly.  As such, it has a sync blacklist in place so it doesn't show up in Ubuntu's repos during autosyncs.

Concurrently, however, Ubuntu has moved the Chromium Browser package to 'snaps' - because of the way source packages and binary names and such are, we have to have a different name for it to avoid conflicts.  While I do not have specifics on how `chromium-chromedriver` got its name that way, I can state that it serves a completely different binary package purpose - it's a transitional package that simply installs the Chromium snap which has the chromium driver / Selenium available in it, and is wholly dependent on `snapd` and the Snaps infrastructure to function and to be set up on your system to function.

Treat them as completely different, independent packages, since we no longer ship Selenium and such directly and instead do it via snaps here in Ubuntu.